# Что означает данная строка?

Tags: java, время

```
public static boolean validDate(String dateString) {
    return DateUtil.parse(dateString) != null; // эта строка
}
```

Вот метод parse(String) из  класса DateUtil:

```
public static LocalDate parse(String dateString) {
        try {
            return DATE_FORMATTER.parse(dateString, LocalDate::from);
                } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
                    return null;
                }
        }
```

Comment: в методе parse логика такая, что если при попытке распарсить возникает исключение, то возвращается null, а метод validDate смотрит результат метода parse, и если вернулся null - значит дата не распарсилась, возвращаем false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сам метод у Вас типа boolean. Поэтому, я думаю, что строка вида `return true;` Вас не должна была бы удивить. Выражение `DateUtil.parse(dateString) != null` возвращает как раз булен.

Вся эта "подозрительная строка" эквивалентна такой

```
if (DateUtil.parse(dateString) != null) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

но так пишут только самые начинающие.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateUtil.parse(dateString) != null
```

возвращает `true`, если `parse()` вернет не `null`, иначе `false`

смысл в том, что если строка распарсится до даты, то функция вернет *ок, да эта строка содержит какую то дату*